# Zariski topology - why are all intersections of non-empty open sets non-empty?

Tags: general-topology

This is stated in a book ("Topologie", F. Toenniessen, p. 13).

Let $(\mathbb Z, \mathcal T)$ be a topological space with the Zariski-topology

$$\mathcal T = \{A \subseteq \mathbb Z : |A^c| < \infty \}. $$

Choose $I = \mathbb Z$ as an index set and $A_i = \mathbb Z \setminus \{i\}$ for $i \in I$. Then,

$$ \bigcap_{i \in I} A_i = \left ( \left ( \bigcap_{i \in I} \{ i \}^c \right)^c \right)^c = \left( \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb Z} \{ i \} \right)^c = \mathbb Z^c = \varnothing.$$

Isn‘t this a counter example? Should it be "all finite intersections"?

Comment: That's the cofinite topology, not the Zariski topology which means something else. For example, the Zariski topology in $Spec(\mathbb{Z})$ is not the cofinite topology as $\{(0)\}$ is not closed. Also, the Zariski topology on $\mathbb{A}^2_k$ is not the cofinite topology either..

Comment: "Counterexample" to what statement, specifically? People often do not read your textbook and, although hardly anything prevents you from seeking help only by people who have done so, it's widely believed that most of these questions solve themselves when the person who asks is forced to read the theorems he thinks he knows.

Comment: @Sassatelli Giulio A counterexample to the statement in the headline.

Comment: @ATW Ah, ok, that's just false for that topology (in point of fact, a topology has the property in the title if and only if the intersection of all the non-empty open sets is non-empty, i.e. if and only if it has a dense point).